# Navigation Bar not displaying all links of mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am currently facing an issue with the website I am working on using Wordpress.

When I go down to the mobile I get a mobile icon that is produced and when I click it, it only displays 2 links and then after the top 2 the rest of the links seem to disappear.

This is what the current mobile navigation looks like when it is toggled:

[View the current mobile navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWTGX.png)

I have tried to change the whole of the height and also add in a background colour regarding the css, as it is Wordpress I will try and post images of the current coding.

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvRQf.png)

```
<nav role="navigation"> 
  <div class="menu-main-menu-bliss-container">
   <ul id="navigation" class="navigation">
     <li id="menu-item-6725" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6725"><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-6793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-6793"><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-6794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6794"><a href=""><span>Bliss Mission</span></a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-6795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6795"><a href=""><span>Hayley Shaw</span></a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-6796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6796"><a href=""><span>Akhanda Yoga</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
   <li id="menu-item-6797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-6797"><a href="#"><span>Yoga</span></a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-6798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6798"><a href="/classes-schedule/"><span>Class Schedule</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6799"><a href="/private-lessons"><span>Private Lessons</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6800"><a href="/bliss-events"><span>Events</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6801" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6801"><a href="/retreats"><span>Retreats</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
    <li id="menu-item-6803" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6803"><a href="/categories"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6804"><a href="/blog"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6805" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6805"><a href="/contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6806" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6806"><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Donate</span></a></li>
  </ul></div>
</nav>
```

The CSS does actually have a height where the whole of the navigation should be displayed and a z-index to place the nav above everything else.

Comment: share some code? not in image but in snippet, not only html but css and jquery too

Comment: I have added in the navigation bar code to the question

Comment: Here is a link to the [site](http://blissmission.co.uk)

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden` property for `.header_mid_inner` class

Comment: Thank you @htmlbrewery ! Is there anyway I can change the background color? As when I seem to do this and toggle the event the color seems to stay as it is

Comment: @cmiotk you can set `background-color` at `.menu-main-menu-bliss-container` class, now by default all div have transparent background.

Comment: You would change the value for the background in your style.css file:

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
style.css?ver=1.0.0:9005
.menu-main-menu-bliss-container {
    background-color: rgba(43,39,55,0.95);
}